# didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo duplicate file when saving

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a simple App than you have the possibility to choose an existent video from photo library or you can take a video with UIImagePickerController.

I added the following code for when I make a new video with camera I can save it in photo Gallery if I need in the future.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

// Get the selected Video.
NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
// Convert to Video data.
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];

// Save Video to Photo Album
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
NSURL *recordedVideoURL= [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
if ([library videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum:recordedVideoURL]) {
    [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:recordedVideoURL
                                completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){}
     ];
} 
[library release];

[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];

}
```

Now my issue is when I select a video from Photo Library this same video is duplicated as this code save always a new video.

Is it a way to detect if you selected the video from Photo Library ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before saving the video, check the imagePickerController's **sourceType**. Only save the video if sourceType is **UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera**.

```
if (picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {
    // Save the video 
}
```